# Value Does not fall within the expected range. (Runtime Error)

Tags: c#, class, runtime-error, opc

I am converting a Windows Form from VB to C# and I ran in to an error when I attempted to do a synchronized read of my OPC tags.

I have this code:

```
public partial class FrmPartialMain : Form
{   
    RsiOPCAuto.OPCServer oOpcServer;
    RsiOPCAuto.OPCGroup oOpcGroup;

    int ClHandle; //this is set to 1 in another part of the code.
    int SvHandle;


    int OpcDsCashe = 1;
    int OpcDsDevice = 2;
    private void cmdSyncRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int lNumItems = oOpcGroup.OPCItems.Count; // = 3
        int[] h = new int[lNumItems];
        Array arValues = new int[lNumItems];
        Array arHandles;
        Array arErrors;
        object Qualities;
        object Timestamps;


        h[ClHandle - 1] = oOpcGroup.OPCItems.Item(ClHandle).ServerHandle;  
        arHandles = (Array)h;
        //Error on the next line bellow.
        oOpcGroup.SyncRead((short)OpcDsDevice, lNumItems, ref arHandles, out arValues, out arErrors, out Qualities, out Timestamps);


        txtSubValue.Text = Convert.ToString(arValues.GetValue(0));
    }
}
```

oOpcGroup.Read() reads the value, quality and timestamp information for one or more items in a group. and the return type looks like this:

```
 SyncRead(short Source, int NumItems, ref System.Array ServerHandles, out System.Array Values, out System.Array Errors, out object Qualities, out object TimeStamps);
```

Running this code gives me the error in the title, Value Does not fall within the expected range. Any ideas of what i might be doing wrong here?

Brainstorm away!

Comment: Please add the Exception with stacktrace, indicate which line the the linenumber refers to.

Comment: it looks like ClHandle is never set, so it starts at 0, then you subtract 1 from it which would leave you an array index of -1 which is not a valid index.

Comment: @pstrjds This is just a small portion of my code, ClHandle is set to 1 at an earlier stage.

Comment: @Henrik It is set to 1 at an earlier stage in the code.

Comment: What does `SyncRead` look like?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Hi Daniel! I actually found the cause of this error a minute ago. arValues needed to be an object array for this to work. Debugs just fine now, but thank you for again for taking your time. I'm pretty sure I will face another problem pretty soon, I need to convert "WithEvents" somehow, and it doesn't seem to exist in C#.

Comment: @Charp: There is no such thing in C#. You will have to subscribe to the events "traditionally".

Comment: @DanielHilgarth From what i have read it doesn't seem to be needed at all. I can see the events of my variable in the dropdown list that pops up after the "." (ctrl + space). But the problem is that I need to add new public void inside the public partial class (one that looks similar to when you add code to a button for example). the OPCGroup has events and is assigned like this in in my vb code: Dim WithEvents oOpcGroup As RsiOPCAuto.OPCGroup and in my vb project I can see the events in the second combobox at the top of my code. http://i.imgur.com/3XERw.png <-- i want this.

Comment: Clicking the event creates the "Private Sub oOpcGroup_DataChange(ByVal TransactionID As I..." code. I don't know how to create the equivalent code in C#.

Comment: Type `oOpcGroup.EventName += <Tab><Tab>`. After you typed the `+=` it offers to create the assignment which you accept with the first tab. With assignment, I mean the part like this: `new ButtonClickDelegate(oOpcGroup_DataChange)`. The second tab offers to create the not yet existing method `oOpcGroup_DataChange`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Daniel! Quick question. How do I use VarType in C#? I have an if-loop that finds the type of an item in an array. If VarType(ItemValues(i)) And Not VariantType.Array Then txtSubValue.Text = ItemValues(i) I am guessing i'll need to use .GetType(), but how?

Comment: This warrants its own question :)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth A new question has been posted, take a look!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Where should I put oOpcGroup.EventName += <Tab><Tab>? I put them in public form {} but I get a run-time error telling me that the value cannot be null and that the parameter name is o. http://i.imgur.com/Blip1.png

Comment: You need to put it after the line the initializes `oOpcGroup` with a value.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Thank you! Finally finished converting this project. It works even better than the original one with VB syntax :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's alive!

This is the fixed code:

```
public partial class FrmPartialMain : Form
{   
    RsiOPCAuto.OPCServer oOpcServer;
    RsiOPCAuto.OPCGroup oOpcGroup;

    int ClHandle; //this is set to 1 in another part of the code.
    int SvHandle;


    int OpcDsCashe = 1;
    int OpcDsDevice = 2;
    private void cmdSyncRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                                                                                  //Sync Read
    {
        int lNumItems = oOpcGroup.OPCItems.Count;
        int[] arH = new int[1 + lNumItems];
        Array arValues = new object[1 + lNumItems]; //<-- This needed to be an object array.
        Array arHandles;
        Array arErrors;
        object Qualities;
        object Timestamps;

        arH[ClHandle] = oOpcGroup.OPCItems.Item(ClHandle).ServerHandle;

        arHandles = (Array)arH;
        oOpcGroup.SyncRead((short)OpcDsDevice, lNumItems, ref arHandles, out arValues, out arErrors, out Qualities, out Timestamps);

        txtSubValue.Text = Convert.ToString(arValues.GetValue(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you'd explain what the problem was and what the solution was in your answer.